# Is my ranking in total order?

Tags: relations, order-theory

I ask a person to fill a questionnaire to give a score to a set of items, without loss of generality, he scores items $X=\{a, b, c, d, e\}$ in a 5 point scale $[1..5]$. He is allowed to give same score to different items, a table can be gotten:

```
               ________________________________
          |  1      2      3      4       5    |
  .-------+-------------------------------------
  |  a    |                               x    |
  |  b    |                       x            |
  |  c    |                x                   |
  |  d    |                       x            |
  |  e    |                x                   |
  '-------+------------------------------------'
```

Then I define the preference relationship $\succeq$, that $x\succeq y, x,y\in X $ means $x$ is weakly preferred to $y$ (means he either strictly prefers x to y or is indifferent between the two). Thus, should my ranking be $a\succeq(b,d)\succeq(c,e)$? And can I say this ranking is in total order? To me the question is weather does the order satisfy antisymmetry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clearly not antisymetric, since $b$ and $d$ are equally prefered but they aren't the same object

Comment: So for the antisymmetric: $b\succeq d$ and $d\succeq b$ implies $b=d$, the $=$ must mean the $b$ and $d$ same object? I cannot say $=$ means they hold the same preference levels, so it is antisymmetric? If it does not satisfy antisymmetr, is this ranking in a total preorder?

Comment: No, they must be the same object, that's the definition of antisymmetry:
$\preceq$ is antisymmetric $\Leftrightarrow \forall x\forall y (x \preceq y \land y \preceq x \rightarrow x=y)$.

However, if you define an equivalence relation like follows: $a \sim b \Leftrightarrow a \preceq b \land b \preceq a$ then you can say that the quocient set $X / \sim$ with the expected order is totally ordered since the class of $b$ and the class of $d$ is the same
I.e., you identify the equivalent objects as the same one

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a total order on the set of three elements $\{\{a\}, \{b,d\},\{c,e\}\}$ that you get by "identifying" the original elements when their scores match. (You can say that more formally as the elements of the partition determined by the scoring function.)

It's not a total order on the original set since neither $b$ nor $d$ is preferred to the other.

Comment: Dear Prof.Bolker, thank you for your comment. So I assume it is a preorder. Additionally, it is not a total preorder as there is no strong connectedness.